# VAR lag selection heavily depends on maximum lag investigated

Tags: aic, vector-autoregression, lags, vector-error-correction-model

I am fitting an Error Correction Model with two monthly price time series.
In Stata I am using the `varsoc` command to determine the number of lags that are appropriate.

```
varsoc variable1 variable2
```

If I run `varsoc` with the default 4 `maxlags`, the suggested lag length using AIC/FPE is 3.
However, if I run varsoc with `maxlag(12)` option, 12 lags are suggested.
If I use `maxlag(20)`, 13 lags are suggested.

1. Why is `varsoc` so sensitive to the number of `maxlag`?
2. If this is the case, how should I decide which `maxlag` to use? Running `varsoc` on the time series seperately yields 8 lags (if a larger `maxlag` is chosen).

Comment: Regarding the close vote, I don't think this question belongs to Stack Overflow because the issue seems to be statistical rather than programming-specific. Regarding error correction model, it seems to be vector error correction model (VECM) rather than single-equation error correction model (ECM); if this is so, I suggest editing the post accordingly.

Comment: Low, let me know if something is still unclear. Otherwise, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`varsoc`](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsvarsoc.pdf) considers full (unrestricted) VAR or VECM models with lags 1 through `maxlag`. It may happen that the user sets `maxlag` to a relatively low number such that the best model in AIC or FPE sense is excluded. This seems to be happening for `maxlag(4)` and `maxlag(12)`. However, I suspect the AIC- or FPE-suggested lag order would not grow infinitely. It might just be the case that a VAR(13) model fits the data relatively better than a VAR(3) or VAR(12), even after penalizing the number of parameters in the model. You should also not be surprised that a VAR(3) is selected rather than a VAR(4) when you set `maxlag(4)`. AIC and FPE need not decrease monotonically until the "optimal" lag and increase monotonically after that.

If you think that a VAR(13) is nonsensical and the lag order is too high, then perhaps you have excluded a relevant variable or neglected seasonality or a structural change, or the model suffers from yet another fault.